# What's the best way to configure a testing environment in laravel 5?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm just getting to grips with Laravel5, having some previous experience with L4. One of the problems I'm having is with environment configuration, mainly with regards to testing.

I'm trying to connect to a mysqlite database & after much searching around, the best I've come up with is adding a conditional to the config file as follows:

```
'default' => $app->environment('testing') ? 'sqlite':'mysql'
```

And in my phpunit.xml file:

```
<php>
        <env name="APP_ENV" value="testing"/>
        <env name="CACHE_DRIVER" value="array"/>
        <env name="SESSION_DRIVER" value="array"/>
        <env name="QUEUE_DRIVER" value="sync"/>
</php>
```

However, now when I try to run my test suite I receive the following error:

```
ReflectionException: Class env does not exist.
```

At this point my only option appears to be to create two separate .env files, 'testing' and 'local', renaming them to '.env' as i need them. This is obviously not efficient or tolerable. Any advice?

Comment: Is you phpunit.xml file similar to the original one ? https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/phpunit.xml

Comment: It is pretty much identical, yeah. The only changes being within the 'testsuites' node.

Comment: Did you run a `composer install` before ?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to setup a different database connection setting up an env environment variable in the database.php config:

config/database.php

```
-    'default' => 'mysql',
+    'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION','mysql'),
```

phpunit.xml

```
<env name="DB_CONNECTION" value="sqlite"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

As the doc show, when you run phpunit, the default APP_ENV is `testing` and be set in `phpunit.xml` (http://laravel.com/docs/testing#introduction). but lumen **have no any rule** to load config file such as `.env.testing` or `.env.production` for us.

but, laravel provide us with a `callback`.

```
  $app->detectEnvironment(function() use ($app){
       if (file_exists(__DIR__.'/../'.'.env.' .getenv('APP_ENV') )) {
           $app->loadEnvironmentFrom('.env.'. getenv('APP_ENV') );
       }
   });
```

run some command under specify enviroment:

```
APP_ENV=testing artisan serve
```

then app will load config from `/.env.testing`

note:

> if you take my idea, --env option is invalid. the another approach is adding prefix APP_ENV=testing. i think it is a bug of laravel , because the DetectEnvironment Closure will not be call when running command under cli mode.